# Can anyone tell me if this is a weed

Tags: weed-control

Can anyone tell me what this is? I have about 10 in my yard. At first I thought they were blueberries, then mayby peach or nectarine trees. But they don't match anything. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: any smell from the leaf?  if you break it is there sticky white sap?

Comment: No sap, it looked like a stick very dry. Smelt kinda like cut grass or just a normal leaf.

Comment: Does look like peach.

Comment: Any squirrel action around the pot? Maybe they buried a peach pit.

Comment: If you don't want it , it is a weed.

Comment: Might be a willow.